# Getting The Localized Date

Tags: java, android, date

I know this is a pretty n00by question but it's sort of confusing me as there are so many ways to do it.

I live in England so our date is 'Day-Month-Year'. So on my app I want to store the date when something happens and then display it. But in America the date is 'Month-Day-Year', previously I have gotten several emails saying that someone did something on the 12 January and it saying they did it the 1 December.

I can get the Locale from the device, so I'm wonder what is the best way to get the localized date with Day, Month and Year in it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK);
System.out.println("Time: "+ df.format(date)); // or whatever you want to do with it.
```

Comment: How do i get the date as a string from that?

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context context)` returns the current locale's format.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` class. Look instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

It can produce String to either format selected by you or format default for current JVM/device/Locale

For instance:

```
final String FORMAT="yyyy-MM-dd";
return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```